# Angular $resource receives error although server returns correctly

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mongoose, angular-resource

I'm trying to retrieve JSON data from a MongoDB server through Express, Mongoose and Angular `$resource`. Although the server obviously returns the correct data, the error function is always called and a strange error is shown.

This is (sort of) the controller:

```
.controller('DefaultContentController',
    ['$scope',
    '$location',
    'pageFactory',
    function($scope, $location, pageFactory) {
        var path = $location.path().split('/');

        pageFactory.getPages().get({slug:path[1]})
            .$promise.then(
               function(response) {
                   console.log(response);
               },
               function(response) {
                   console.log("Error: " +  response.status);
                   console.log("Status text: " + response.statusText);
               }
            );
        }])
```

`pageFactory.getPages` is defined as

```
        this.getPages = function(){
            return $resource("http://localhost:3000/pages/:slug", {});
        };
```

Executing this with a location that evaluates to a slug of `packages` results in the following:

- No JavaScript error or anything else in the console of the browser
- my custom error output in the console:
  `Error: -1`
  `Status text:`
- The server reports `GET /pages/packages 200 2.683 ms - 303` in its log output

If I enter the location in a browser the correct JSON response is displayed, so obviously the server itself is working properly. The raw response (as logged by Firefox HttpRequrester extension) is

```
GET http://localhost:3000/pages/packages

 -- response --
200 OK
X-Powered-By:  Express
Content-Type:  application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length:  305
Etag:  W/"131-BTgYonvS22Ju7nZNcmxv0w"
Date:  Thu, 24 Mar 2016 12:44:43 GMT

[{"_id":"56f3c58ebbea0d5a0e39630a","updatedAt":"2016-03-24T10:46:38.463Z","createdAt":"2016-03-24T10:46:38.463Z","slug":"packages","title":"Packages","html":"<p>As long as there is no auto-generated package documentation this page will simply contain a list of available packages.</p>","__v":0,"tabs":[]}]
```

Is there any idea where I can investigate further?